# How can I plot objects outside of an axes using Line or annotation objects in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, properties, annotations, matlab-figure

I want to create a line with circular markers at each data point outside the axes in a MATLAB figure, similar to what

```
line([x1 x2],[y1 y2],'Color','k','Marker','o')
```

would produce.

To place the line object outside the axes, I have simply tried using `annotation`:

```
annotation('line',phi1([x1 x2]),phi2([y1 y2]),'Color','k','Marker','o')
```

where `phi1` and `phi2` are appropriate coordinate transforms to fit the coordinates `x` and `y` inside the axes of the current figure.

I expected this to work since line objects have a `marker` property. However, with `annotation`, I am getting the following error message:

```
Error using matlab.graphics.shape.Line/set
There is no Marker property on the Line class.

Error in matlab.graphics.chart.internal.ctorHelper (line 8)
    set(obj, pvpairs{:});

Error in matlab.graphics.shape.Line

Error in annotation (line 128)
        h = matlab.graphics.shape.Line(aargs{:});
```

Similarly, when plotting a rectangle with the `annotation` function, one cannot set the `Curvature` property. It seems that `annotation` does not support these kinds of properties, even though it creates a line or rectangle object just like the `line` or `rectangle` functions would. I tried fiddling around with the annotation handles and children, but no success there.

Any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [different types of annotation objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) are a separate set of class types than the usual [`line`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html) or [`rectangle`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html) objects, supporting a reduced set of properties. For example, a typical `line` object is of class type `matlab.graphics.primitive.Line`, but an annotation line object is of class type `matlab.graphics.shape.Line`.

Instead of using [`annotation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) objects, you can simply set the [`'Clipping'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.line-properties.html#bubwptp-1_sep_shared-Clipping) of the `line` and `rectangle` objects to `'off'` to allow them to individually render outside of the axes limits. For example, this code:

```
hAxes = subplot(1, 2, 1);
axis(hAxes, [0 1 0 1]);    % Freeze axis limits
hLine = line([0.5 2], [0.5 0.5], 'Color', 'k', ...
                                 'Marker', 'o', ...
                                 'Clipping', 'off');
hRect = rectangle(hAxes, 'Position', [1.5 0.1 1 0.25], ...
                         'Curvature', [0.2 0.2], ...
                         'FaceColor', 'r', ...
                         'Clipping', 'off');
```

Produces this plot:

[image]

Alternatively, you can turning clipping off for *all* objects of an axes by turning the [`'Clipping'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7-Clipping) of the *axes* to `'off'`.

Comment: So they are different classes; that makes sense. Is the `Type` property related to the class in some way?

Comment: @LuisMendo: I don't know for sure if the string used for the `Type` property is always uniquely related to a given object class. I'd guess that it *should* be, but can't say for certain if it is. I believe the `Type` property is mainly used for searching for objects using [`findobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) and such.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you for the prompt response

Comment: @Luis: I think the `Type` property is a hold-out from the HG1 days, kept for backwards compatibility. It used to be the only way of knowing the type of a graphics object.

Comment: @Cris I thought that too. But then, in the present case, how would you distinguish between the two classes? Both objects are “`line`”. Or does `class` give more information? (I’m away from computer now)

Comment: @LuisMendo: Calling `class` on the objects returns the two different class types I listed above. Calling `class` on an old HG1 handle would just give you `double` I believe.

Comment: @gnovice That sorts it out then, thanks! So it’s only the default display (typing the variable name in the command window) that says `line` for both